# Change a hyperlink string inside a class to another string on a wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a category name which is being generated strangely and there is a "-" between the category name which is something I dont want. I tried changing it through tradition methods of editing category name and slug but nothing seems to be the problem, it still shows up so I thought ill fix it via jquery but for some reason it wont work with jquery to.

This is the code I am using. The string is tax-incentive within class "elementor-post__categories" . I want the string replaced with "tax incentive" , without the hyphen. For some reason it just wont work.

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.elementor-post__categories').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var updatedHtml = html.replace(/tax-incentive/g, 'tax incentive');
    $(this).html(updatedHtml);
  });
});
```

I also tried putting ".elementor-post__categories a" as the class name because its a hyperlink. Hoped that would work but it didnt.

Comment: Most likely the target DOM hasn't been generated while running the script.

Comment: a) You are confusing _name_ with _slug_. WP replaces spaces in the latter on purpose - because spaces should rather not be used in URLs to begin with. (And if you _insist_ on using them, then you should at least apply proper URL encoding.) b) just changing that link href on the client side will most likely not do the trick - when you click on that link, then WP will try to find the category based on the _slug_ stored in the database. But that value in there _will be_ `tax-incentive`, so with the search term `tax incentive` I am assuming it would not find your category now.

Comment: wow stack overflow has become one of the least helpful places...slugs are the first thing I had checked...and DOM is generated, checked with console.log and alert ...giving random negative ratings for no reasons

Comment: Can you update question and give us the part of HTML that you want to change with JavaScript

Comment: What does `console.log($('.elementor-post__categories').length)` return?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code, targetted a higher class and had to insert a hex space in the string to make it work, but works now. Here is the answer. Also added i to make sure the search was case insensitive.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.elementor-posts-container').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var updatedHtml = html.replace(/tax-incentive/gi, 'tax&nbsp;incentive');
    $(this).html(updatedHtml);
  });
});
```

Appreciate the people who later tried to help genuinely.